# BB10 SystemToast not showing when Modality set to Global

Tags: blackberry-10

I have tried to get a System Toast Popup working on BB10, it works fine when the Modality is set to Application but once I set it to Global it just stops coming up, nothing on the console, no errors or anything:

```
SystemToast *toast = new SystemToast();
        toast->setModality (bb::system::SystemUiModality::Global);
        toast->setBody("Testing");
        toast->setPosition(SystemUiPosition::MiddleCenter);
        toast->show();
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this?
System Dialogs do the same, and Notification Dialogs just don't appear whatever I do.

Answer (score 0):

Global modality no longer seems to work.
https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/BBTEN-669
The API docs are not just updated, i think.
Try using NotificationDialog instead of SystemToast.
platform_notificationdialog.html">http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb_*platform*_notificationdialog.html

EDIT: I overlooked you already tried NotificationDialog ;)

Comment: Damn, I can't open that bug report, says I don't have the Permissions :/

You don't happen to have any little examples of a Notification Dialog do you?
My initial tries resulted in nothing at all showing, and System Dialogs show in App but dim the whole App and don't respond.